# Error increasing memory limit on Intel HAXM

Tags: haxm

I'm trying to increase the memory limit for Intel HAXM.  When I'm in the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager, on the screen where I choose to manually set the value, I get the error

> Invalid input format, please input again! Note: The value must be
>   between 512 MB and 1.9 GB.  Input content must be integer

When I enter the default value (1024 MB), it goes through, but I need to raise it, and I haven't found any other values that work (have tried 2000, 2048, 3072...)  What's going on?  Is this a definition of 'integer' I'm unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I'm running on windows) my problem was the emulator "closed" but the process didn't quit so it was still sitting there not allowing me start another emulator because I "exceed" my Haxm memory limit. So I opened up my Task Manager and looked for the emulator in the processes and sure enough the process was still running. ( it was easy to spot because it was set the amount of ram that I gave the emulator ) so I force quit that process and the emulator fired up again and I went on about my day. Hope this helps!